# 2 plot diagrams appear when only creating 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

I'm trying to plot a data frame in a line graph and customise the labels, title, etc. However, it seems to create an empty diagram instead.

```
plot_df= plt.plot(df)

plt.figure(figsize=(30,8))
plt.title("TITLE.", fontsize=24)

plt.xticks(rotation=30, horizontalalignment="center", fontsize=16)
plt.yticks(fontsize=16)

plt.xlabel("X", fontsize=21, labelpad=12)
plt.ylabel("Y", fontsize=21, labelpad=8)
display(plot_df)
```

Said diagrams:
[image: plot with intended content]

[image: plot with intended customisations]

So the question here is, how do I customise the intended plot without conjuring up an empty one?

Comment: When there is not plot created yet, `plt.plot(df)` will create a new plot.  Then, when calling `plt.figure(...)` yet another (empty) plot is created.  If you'd call `plt.figure(...)` before `plt.plot(df)` you'd avoid that empty plot.  By the way, instead of `display(plot_df)`, one normally calls `plt.show()` to show the resulting plot (how this works exactly, depends on the environment where you're running Python and matplotlib).

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the explanation! Am I right to understand that by calling `plt.plot(df)`  **after** `plt.figure(...)`, the diagram places itself inside of `plt.figure(...)`?

Comment: Indeed. Plotting default occurs in the last created figure and subplot. If there aren't any yet, a default one will be created.